# Adding vector elements into a data file

Tags: c++, vector

I have asked the user to input several string elements to create a vector of strings and would like to print them into a data file.

```
fstream file_name;
string user_input_file;
vector<vector<string>>read_in_vector;

file_name.open(user_input_file.c_str());

cout << "You have entered:" << endl;
        cout << "Row Desc:  " << add_row << endl;
        cout << "Username:  " << add_username << endl;
        cout << "Password:  " << add_password << endl;
        cout << "Notes: " << add_notes << endl << endl;
vector<string>temp = { add_row,add_username,add_password,add_notes };
```

how would i add that element of the vector called temp
into the data file without erasing the existing parts of the datafile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fstream::[operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), you can append to the end of the file/stream/buffer/whatever, which I think is what you want if I'm reading this correctly. Usage:

```
file_name << temp[0];
```

This will safely append the text onto the file without modifying the rest of its contents.